# If derivative is non zero then a map from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is not surjective

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $v : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a differentiable function such that  $\frac{dv}{dt} \neq 0 \ \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$. How can we prove that $v$ is not surjective.

I think if $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is nonzero, then the map is invertible ( by inverse function theorem). This implies that the map $v$ is injective as well. Which would imply that the map, if surjective, would become bijective. But, I think a bijective map from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ must be cdiscontinuous. Am I right? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bijective map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$ cannot indeed be continuous.If it were, it would be a homeomorphism, but this cannot be the case since removing a point from $\mathbb R$ disconnects it while the same is not true for $\mathbb R^2$.

It is also true that a $C^1$ map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$ cannot be surjective. That follows from Sard's theorem.

Also, what you say about the inverse function theorem is incorrect. If the derivative of $f$ does not vanish, then $f$ is locally injective, but certainly not surjective or injective in general. Just take $f(t)=(\cos(t), \sin(t))$.

Comment: sorry, I still entirely dont get how does the surjectivity follow from sard's theorem? Sard' s theorem states that the image of the points where derivative is zero is a negligible set. How does that be useful here?

Comment: @vidyarthi Sard's theorem states that the image of points whose differentials are not surjective is negligible. In the case of a map $f$ from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$, for all $x \in \mathbb R$ the differential $df(x)$ is not surjective. So Sard's theorem says that $f(\mathbb R)$ is negligible in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: actually, does not sard theorem say what I have told before, or would what you say and I say are both equivalent?

Comment: @vidyarthi It does not say what you wrote (or maybe what you wrote is a particular case for functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Please read e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem